# WebView is not open up the "http://itunes.apple.com"

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using this code to open the web url into `UIWebView.`

For if part the URL is properly open in `UIWebView` but the "http://itunes.apple.com...." URL is not open in `UIWebView.`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url;
    if (int_btnTag == 0)
    {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.elsner.com/"];
    }
    else if (int_btnTag == 1)
    {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/emicalculator-1.0/id528922578?ls=1&mt=8"];
    }

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Is there any other way to open this apple link in `UIWebView..`.?

If there is then please suggest me.

thanks in advance...

Comment: @elppa... yes i want to open links to the application's webview instead browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url;
    if (int_btnTag == 0)
    {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.elsner.com/"];
    }
    else if (int_btnTag == 1)
    {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/emicalculator-1.0/id528922578?ls=1&mt=8"];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];




    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: @Jignesh Fadadu Is this the thing you were looking for?

Comment: @sanchitsingh....i want to open link into the application & not wanted to go outside the applicaton.

Comment: @JigneshFadadu thats not possible with the iTunes link. You have to open it outside your application i.e at appstore app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, that page is configured in the iPhone to launch the appstore instead.

Comment: thanks for the response....i am not able to load the application in the webview using this code...

Comment: @JigneshFadadu It will open from a browser, but any app that calls the appstore, has to instead open the actual appstore in the iphone.